# Big Sized files download links for frontend users component

Tags: component, file-upload, media-manager

Is there any component which allows large files management. I would like to provide download links for frontend users but but the file size excedes 500MB. On the other side just the logged in users should be able to access the download link.

Comment: Depending on your hosting allowances, it may be best to use an extension that has integration with 3rd party services, such as Dropbox. Joomla 4 will have this :)

Answer (score 1):

Docman can do that. If you hit any limits then you can increase them in the Docman settings, the Joomla settings, and the PHP server settings.